# Align caption text to center and have its label to the left

Tags: captions

I am trying to have the caption of a figure aligned as it is below:

[image]

**Description:** I included a few rows of text above and below the figure to see the alignment of the caption. It seems to me that the text of the caption is aligned to center while the label *Fig. 1.1.1.* is somehow floating at the lest of the text.

Here's what I tried:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering\captionsetup{format = hang}

    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{assets/basic}
    \caption{Some long caption here}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

The multiple rows in the caption are correctly justified under the first, but the entire caption box is then aligned to the left.

How can I achieve that effect, please?

**EDIT**

I have created an example document to illustrate my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption, threeparttable}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\title{FigureCaption}
\author{Victor Barbu}

\begin{document}

\section{Testing Captions}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering\captionsetup{format = hang}

    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{pic}
    \caption{The graph on $V = \{1,\ldots,7\}$ with edge set\\ $E = \{(1,2),(1,5),(2,5),(3,4),(5,7)\}$}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The big question is whether \captionsetup{justification=centering} has already been used or is the default for this document class.  The label format indicates that some additional \captionsetup has been used.

Comment: we need to see a complete small document, which show your problem.  however, see if `\captionsetup{format = hang, width=7cm}` gives what you looking for.

Comment: @JohnKormylo couldn't say. the image is a screenshot of a book

Comment: @Zarko it doesn't seem like what I need. Basically what I need is to have the caption text centered while the label should be ignored from centering calculation, or at least have it all centered as a whole

Comment: So basically you need a \phantom{\fnum@figure} to the right of the text.  Tricky!

Comment: @Victor, (i) please provide an example of document with your caption (enough long caption's text that we can see what you like to obtain). (ii) from your description is difficult imagine your demand (iii) as far as i imagine now your demand, i afraid that your demand lead to bad typographic design.

Comment: @Zarko why would that be a bad design? As far as I can see in the screenshot of the book I posted, the label lays at the left of the text with the text centered in the page. Isn't that what you see too? Why is my demand unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i understood your question you looking for something like this:

[image]

but i might be wrong :-(

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

%\title{FigureCaption}
%\author{Victor Barbu}

\begin{document}

%\section{Testing Captions}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering\captionsetup{format = hang, width=8cm}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{pic}
    \caption{The graph on $V = \{1,\ldots,7\}$ with edge set $E = \{(1,2),(1,5),(2,5),(3,4),(5,7)\}$}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I want indeed!